# Flatten data.table (data.frame) with custom indexing

Tags: r, data.table

Is there an easy way to flatten a data.table with keeping custom indexes.

Problem statement:
I have a database where the data met minute uploads per 5 minutes in five different columns. I eventually want to interpolate the missing values using na.approx,but I have to come up with a way to flatten the data.table with their right datetime instance.

Example data:

```
data <- data.frame(datetime = c("2018-01-01 10:00:00", 
                            "2018-01-01 10:05:00", 
                            "2018-01-01 10:10:00", 
                            "2018-01-01 18:00:00", 
                            "2018-01-01 18:05:00"),
               value_1 = c(0, 45, NA, NA, 170),
               value_2 = c(10, 50, 70, 130, 175),
               value_3 = c(20, 60, 85, 135, 180),
               value_4 = c(30, NA, 95, 150, 190),
               value_5 = c(30, 70, 110, 160, 200)
               ) %>% data.table()
data$datetime <- as.POSIXct(data$datetime)
```

Interpolation on value_1 right now gives:

```
na.approx(data$value_1, x = data$datetime)
[1]   0.00000  45.00000  46.30208 168.69792 170.00000
```

while I would expect: c(0, 45, 70, 120, 170)

Output:

[image: required output of flattening]

I have come up with a solution but it is not neat:

```
times <- c(data$datetime + 60, data$datetime + 120, data$datetime + 180, data$datetime + 180, data$datetime + 240)
test <- flatten(data[, -c("datetime")])
data.table(datetime = times, values = test)
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do it better?

Comment: Why would you expect the output to be `c(0, 45, 70, 120, 170)`? The `na.approx` output is sound given the datetime input

Comment: @JonnyPhelps, I expect the output to be like that because row 1 represent value_# representsa value between 10:00 and 10:04, row 2 is the value between 10:05 and 10:09, etc..
As the value of 10:08 is NA, I want to interpolate it using 10:07 and 10:09 instead of the values in 10:07 and 18:05.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this ok?

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
dt <- as.data.table(data)
increment <- 60 # seconds
# wide to long
dt_long <- melt(dt, id.vars = "datetime")
# add increments to datetime, retaining values for each set of datetime
dt_frame <- dt_long[, .(new_datetime = seq(datetime[1], datetime[1]+(increment*(.N-1)), by=increment),
                        value = value), 
               by=datetime]
dt_frame[, value2 := na.approx(value, new_datetime)]

# additions, keep original datetime, and cast back to wide format
dt_frame[, i := 1:.N, by = datetime]
out <- dcast(dt_frame, datetime~i, value.var="value2")
rename_these <- setdiff(names(out), "datetime")
setnames(out, rename_these, sprintf("value_%s", rename_these))
out[]
```

Comment: YES! This is the solution which is also easy upscalable. Thank you! The only thing is that it has to get back into the original format so it can be inplemented within the different methods. I could devide it back using `data$value_1 <- dt_frame[1:(nrow(dt_frame)/5)]$value2` for all five values but that doesn't look like a pretty solution imho.

Comment: No worries, edited the answer to reshape back to original format